# Laravel 5.4 EloquentUserProvider override validateCredentials

Tags: laravel

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
```

How to override a method `validateCredentials` in the class `EloquentUserProvider`?? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own UserProvider and then you can override the functions from  the original UserProvider.

First you create the CustomUserProvider:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;

class CustomUserProvider extends UserProvider {

  public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
  {
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
  }

}
```

Then you register your new CustomUserProvider in config/app.php

```
'providers' => array(
   ... On the bottom, must be down to override the default UserProvider
   'Your\Namespace\CustomUserProvider'
),
```

Answer (score 32):

In Laravel 5.4 you don't need to register your *CustomUserProvider* in *config/app.php*.

See [this blog article](https://return2.net/laravel-auth-custom-login-validation/) for detailed instructions.

The short form:

First, create a *CustomUserProvider.php* file in your *Providers* directory:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider as UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;


class CustomUserProvider extends UserProvider {

    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }

}
```

After this, change the `boot()` Method in your *AuthServiceProvider.php* file:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::provider('customuserprovider', function($app, array $config) {
        return new CustomUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
    });
}
```

Now, you can use the provider by adding the driver name to your *config/auth.php* file:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'customuserprovider',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Working in Laravel 7 as well