# How to add a custom User Provider in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a Laravel 5.4 app, in which I have to authenticate my admin users from an external API, which when successfully logged in it returns a JSON with user information.

I am creating a custom guard to make this:

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ],

        'custom' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customusers'
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

and this is my custom provider:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'customusers' => [
        'driver' => 'jsonresponse',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ]
],
```

After that, I am not sure how to continue. I've read some tutorials like [the one from George Buckingham](https://www.georgebuckingham.com/blog/laravel-52-auth-custom-user-providers-drivers/), and I have created a custom User provider (Right now I just need it to extend from EloquentUserProvider, eventually I will override some functions to connect to the API)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CustomUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider { 

}
```

then registered it both in App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Auth::provider('jsonresponse', function($app, array $config) {
        return new CustomUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
    });
}
```

and in config/app.php

```
'providers' => [

    // Lots of other providers

    // Own providers
    App\Providers\CustomUserProvider::class,
],
```

But after that, I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher, instance of
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in
>   /var/www/public/iberorides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
>   on line 612 and defined

If I override the constructor of my CustomUserProvider and change the params in the closure in AuthServiceProvider, I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bootProvider()
>   must be an instance of Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider, instance of
>   App\Providers\IberoUserProvider given, called in
>   /var/www/public/iberorides/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
>   on line 771 and defined

This makes me think I am not doing things the right way.

Could someone put me in the right direction?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution was simple.

First, despite what other tutorials said, you do not have to register the `CustomUserProvider` in your config providers (Laravel 5.4 here). This was the cause of the errors I was getting.

I only had to override two methods from `EloquentUserProvider`, `retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)` where you return a model based on the credentials provided, and `validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)` where you return a boolean depending on whether credentials are correct.

You can use this same custom provider class with many providers, not just one, e.g.

```
'providers' => [
    'customusers' => [
        'driver' => 'jsonresponse',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'customadmins' => [
        'driver' => 'jsonresponse',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

After that, when you need to check auth with any provider, you need to provide the provider as guard e.g. `Auth::guard('customusers')`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to create a step-by-step answer for a similar problem with your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46224576/2056125

Comment: Hey! I'm really new building laravel apps, i'm working on a similar scenario, but i'm confusing on how to override the "retrieveByCredentials" and "validateCredentials", in those methods, should i make the API call to the authentication route and build the user model from the API's Json response? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JuniorSilva Happy to help. Why don't you ask that as a question so I can answer there?

Comment: @Bul Ikana, i've just asked a question, i'd be so happy if you could give me a help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Very small customizations of the EloquentUserProvider can be done by means of the following code inside the boot method of your AuthServiceProvider.

```
Auth::provider('eloquent', function($app, array $config)
{
  return new class($app['hash'], $config['model']) extends \Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider
  {

  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions I found quite worked for me, so I figured out a super easy way. (**Laravel 5.4**)

My problem was that I had to allow users to log in with their phone number too.

I override the `EloquentUserProvider`:

```
class PhoneUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        if (!$credentials) {
            return null;
        }

        // Fallback to original email authorization
        if (filter_var($credentials['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return parent::retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
        }

        // Assume we are logging in with a phone number
        return UserModel::where('phone', $credentials['email'])->first();
    }
}
```

And in my `AppServiceProvider` boot methode I added these lines:

`Auth::setProvider(new PhoneUserProvider(app(Hasher::class), UserModel::class));`

You can even set provider in login controller, based on some conditions, etc.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to a 'gist' or 'blog article' with how to properly do it this way.

Comment: There is not more to it. Where are you stuck?
1. Create a custom class that extends EloquentUserProvier
2. Register your user provider to be used as the auth provider by calling Auth::setProvider..

Answer (score 1):

as @Mark Baaijens say

In your `AuthServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::provider('eloquent', function($app, array $config) {
            return new class ($app['hash'], $config['model']) extends EloquentUserProvider {

                public function retrieveById($identifier)
                {
                    $model = $this->createModel();

                    $condition = [$model->getAuthIdentifierName() => $identifier];


                    if ($model instanceof User) {
                        $condition['custom_more_filed'] = 1;
                    }

                    return $model->newQuery()
                                 ->where($condition)
                                 ->first();
                }
            };
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it is of any help to others looking for a way to customize the `retrieveByCredentials` method, it is possible to do so without implementing a custom **UserProvider**. The **EloquentUserProvider** simply takes a credentials array and builds out a **User** query using where clauses for each key/value pair in the array.  So if you already have a class that is defining those credentials, you can simply customize there.

In my case, I had a **ResetPasswordController** that implemented **ResetsPasswords**.  I was looking to modify how the user was selected during submission (using an id and password, rather than email and password), so I overrode the `credentials` method, replacing *email* with *ID_Contact* like so:

```
/**
 * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only(
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
        'token',
        'ID_Contact'
    );
}
```

There were additional places that needed to be customized within the **ResetsPasswords** implementation in order to bring my particular use case into practice (plus the password reset form itself).  Each scenario would be a little different when taking this approach. But this may point some in a helpful direction, depending on your particular requirements.