# The middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-5.6

I have a problem with middleware `RedirectIfAuthenticated`

When I use this middleware in any controller, the **user connect is not detected** (the user connect is NULL). Namely, I use multiple authentication.

**RedirectIfAuthenticated**

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null){
        //dd(Auth::guard($guard)->check()); // when the user is connected the result is null 
        //dd(Auth::user()); // when the user is connect the result is => Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in /Users/diegoruiz/Desktop/app/XXX/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 123


        if($guard == 'admin' && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('admin/accueil');
        }else if($guard == 'employer' && Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
            return redirect('/accueil');
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginController**

```
    class LoginController extends Controller{
       use AuthenticatesUsers;
    ...
    public function __construct(){

    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');//It's not working.
    //$this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');//It's not working.

    }
...
    }
```

**config/auth.php**

```
<?php
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
        'admin-api' =>[
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'employer'=>[
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'employers',
        ],
        'employer-api'=>[
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'employers',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
       'admins'=> [
            'driver' => 'UtilisateurUserProvider',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'employers'=>[
            'driver' => 'UtilisateurUserProvider',
            'model'=> App\Employer::class
        ]
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],



    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'employer' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

    ],

];
```

**UtilisateurUserProvider**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider as UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UtilisateurUserProvider extends UserProvider{

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    public function register(){
        //
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        if (empty($credentials) ||
            (count($credentials) === 1 &&
                array_key_exists('mdp', $credentials))) {
            return;
        }

        // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
        // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
        // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
        $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

        foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
            if (Str::contains($key, 'uti_mdp')) {
                continue;
            }
            if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof Arrayable) {
                $query->whereIn($key, $value);
            } else {
                $query->where($key, $value);
            }
        }

        return $query->first();
    }

    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials){

        $plain = $credentials['mdp'];
        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }

}
```

**Kernel**

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];


    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'entrepriseDatabase' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetEntrepriseDatabase::class,
    ];
}
```

when I use `Auth::user()` in view I have this error

Comment: can you show roughly near line 123 from `verification.blade.php`

Comment: @lagbox the view has only 18 line

Comment: yea sorry, read that wrong, can you provide that view

Comment: dont provide images of code, provide the code ... as text

Comment: @lagbox, you need what provider, you need this provider config/app.php ?

Comment: Have you registered your user provider? i.e. using `Auth::provider("UtilisateurUserProvider", function () { return new UtilisateurUserProvider(); })` ?

Comment: i use this provider to overload methods that belong to the class `EloquentUserProvider`. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069557/laravel-5-4-eloquentuserprovider-override-validatecredentials]

Comment: the 'view' `verification.blade.php`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in **config/auth.php** when you call `Auth::user()` then it'll see for user Auth in auth.php but according to your auth.php it's missing:

```
'providers' => [
   'admins'=> [
        'driver' => 'UtilisateurUserProvider',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
    'employers'=>[
        'driver' => 'UtilisateurUserProvider',
        'model'=> App\Employer::class
    ]
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

You must provide user and in user table add another column role which contain employee, admin etc. your table relation is not right.

Answer (score 0):

I would give another way not using middleware if your task is to clarify the user and redirect them to different routes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tSSR.png)

Comment: Here in my User table I have admin column which clarifies who is the user

Comment: I have an inheritance ([employer]--->[users]<---[admin]) and in the users table I have the email and password. Your solution is fine but I would like to use the middleware created by Laravel